# how does it know that it's not a "variable" but rather a "string"?

Tags: tcl, expect

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set a1 "aaa"
set a2 "bbb"
set a3 "ccc"

for {set b 1} {$b<4} {incr b} {
    set c \$a$b
    send $c
}
```

output :

```
$a1$a2$a3
```

i was hoping to replicate

```
send $a1
send $a2
send $a3
```

the output should have been

aaabbbccc

and yet it is not.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an interpreter handy, and i am a little rusty with TCL, that's what i remember should work, basically you want to deference varoiable value by it's name:

```
set aaa "123"
set bbb "aaa"

# supposed to echo '123':
puts [set $bbb]
```

Comment: Change ``echo`` to ``puts`` and remove the comment

Answer (score 0):

Is it veried using interpreter...
i face the same issue with either its send $c or send [set $c]

c should be set as  `set c [set a$b]`.., Anyway somebody confirm !!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set a1 "aaa"
set a2 "bbb"
set a3 "ccc"

for {set b 1} {$b<4} {incr b} {
    set c [set a$b]
    send $c
}
```